# How can I load Markdown files from a different directory in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I am currently working on a Docusaurus project, and I would like to customize the source directory for Markdown files. By default, Docusaurus looks for documentation files in the **/docs** directory. However, in my case, I want to retrieve Markdown files from a different location, namely **/User** .

[MyFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQOn9.png) 
├── /Docusaurus
│ ├── **/docs**
│ └── .......
├── **/User**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add Path:"../User"

```
presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          path: '../User',
          .....
```